# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reshape the data which is defined as

```
X_train, y_train = series.iloc[:70, :n_steps], series.iloc[:70, -1]
```

to `[samples, timesteps, features]`
but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: `X_train = series.iloc[:70, :n_steps].values` would allow you to reshape.

Comment: n_features=1
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], n_features))